# footer not sticking at the bottom of the page media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, footer

I've tried the following for my site-footer to stay at the bottom of one page only.  (On all other pages, it works as planned but not on one, why is that?)

This is what I am using and although it works, it doesn't work across all mobiles/tablet devices.

help?

Comment: @media screen and (min-width : 567px) and (max-width : 661px) {
 .page-id-94 .site-footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -750px;
  padding-top: 1%;
 }
}

Comment: @media screen and (min-width : 220px) and (max-width : 420px) {
 .page-id-94 .site-footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -1050px;
  padding-top: 1%;
 }
}

Comment: @media screen and (min-width : 221px) and (max-width : 241px) {
 .page-id-94 .site-footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -1500px;
  padding-top: 1%;
 }
}

Comment: If you don't share code, we can't help you.

Comment: Do not do it like that. Use .footer{ position: fixed; bottom:0, left:0;}
Of course this depends on some other things and it's impossible to tell without your whole markup and css.

Comment: I am not sure how to get the code.  I can only copy and paste the stylesheet code I have in front of me.  Can you tell me what code you want me to post here?

Comment: How do I copy my code to paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

I was not exploring your queries, but nowadays you can achieve sticky footer with following markup:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <header>Hi! I'm Header!</header>
    <main>And I'm Main content section! Let's rock!</main>
    <footer>Hi! I'm Footer!</footer>
</div>

.page-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
    height: 50px;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}
```

See the fiddle over [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dnrgbnx5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method in the past and it works perfectly.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <article>Lorem ipsum...</article>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me because copying that code means part of my page(s) are covered with a white container.    I wrote it as .pg-id-94 .site-footer html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: Maybe I need to rewrite the code a different way but I don't know how.